# Sharepoint 'People and groups' - Active Directory Groups Synchronization

Tags: sharepoint, moss

Our environment is as follows -

> ```
> -Windows Active Directory 2003
> -Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard
> -MOSS 2007
> ```

Our problem is simple - I cannot seem to figure out how to import AD groups into the profiles DB. The user profiles have a timer job setup to do full and incremental imports and they are both working fine. We have ~15 active directory groups currently listed under "People and Groups" in SharePoint and as far as I recall nothing special was done to import these.

It was brought to my attention recently that one of the groups email addresses changed and had not updated in MOSS. I am unable to figure out what controls the group synchronization/import. Any advice would be appreciated, whether I'm missing something obvious or if its some obscure STSADM command I've overlooked.

Thanks SO.

Comment: I just noticed something possibly of relevance - the dates added for all of the groups currently in SharePoint correspond to the site BEFORE we upgraded to MOSS. Is it possible that this was a WSS only feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that AD groups are synchronized as user profiles in MOSS/WSS.

You can add an AD group to a SharePoint group (and it works fine), but there will not be a profile for it in the SSP.

See [ajaybawa's blog](http://vspug.com/ajaybawa/2006/09/25/moss-2007-user-and-profiles-import-from-active-directory/) for how to configure the profile import.

Comment: This is mostly correct. The groups that I was seeing in "People and Groups" actually show up once you add the AD group to a SharePoint group. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Timores!